# Archlinux netctl configuration as openvz container

Tags: archlinux, systemd, openvz, proxmox

I'm sorry, but too bad in network manual configuration for systemd and archlinux.
Can you please help me telling me how I can configure netctl to get at the end

```
[root@test etc]# ip addr                                                                     
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN                              
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00                                        
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                                                               
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host                                                                        
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN        
    link/void                                                                                    
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0                                                          
    inet 192.168.0.3/32 brd 192.168.0.3 scope global venet0:0
```

for a correct configuration of my openvz container?

Today I have

```
[root@02-Lab ~]# ip addr                                                               
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN                          
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00                                    
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                                                           
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host                                                                    
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN                          
    link/void
```

Thank you a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: do you have a working DHCP Server? Because then you could just use DHCP with netctl: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl